# Modificar repetidamente url en base a una lista y visitarla

Tags: python, selenium

Tengo un código que uso para modificar ciertos valores de una URL. Explico el proceso, luego del login, llamo a otra url en la cual hago modificaciones. El problema es que necesito entrar a muchas URL similares a estas para hacer la misma operación, la diferencia entre las url es el ID (negrita) https://auto.io/en/users/inventory/**afebecf1-0bc3-4e1e-91ef-dc26de42aca7**/general. Quiero introducir los distintos ID en la URL para poder llamar a todas las URL de los ID

Esos ID yo los tengo en un Excel. Lo que busco es pasarlos a una lista (creo que es lo que me conviene) e ir introduciendo esos valores de ID en el llamado de URL para repetir la acción que necesito. Capaz con alguna función se puede lograr.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import csv

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Martin/Desktop/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://platform.io/en/login/")
user= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form_username"]')
user.send_keys("email")
passwd = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form_password"]')
passwd.send_keys("pass")
l_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login_submit"]')
l_button.click()
time.sleep(1)

driver.get("https://auto.io/en/users/inventory/afebecf1-0bc3-4e1e-91ef-dc26de42aca7/general")
time.sleep(1)
l_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="inventory_general"]/fieldset/div[1]/div[2]/span/span[2]/span')
l_button.click()
```

---

**Edición:**

Intentando leer los datos de un CSV siguiendo la solucion de la respuesta de FJSevilla me he encontrado con un nuevo error. El csv tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
301d5e7b-a75f-4962-f38f-1e6e5db90dcc
f5b2b6ba-a4ce-4e17-b8f8-b8d912e4d6ec
7ed4aaa7-0b3f-44c6-f254-be986985942d
...
```

En realidad es una sola columna como se ve. El codigo con el que intento leerlo es:

```
import csv
with open("Ids para Pausar.csv", 'r') as my_file:
    reader = csv.reader(my_file, delimiter=',')
    my_list = list(reader)
    for id in my_list:
        url = "https://platform.io/en/users/inventory/{}/general".format(id.strip())
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(1)
        l_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="inventory_general"]/fieldset/div[1]/div[2]/span/span[2]/span')
        l_button.click()
        l_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form_submit"]')
        l_button.click()
        time.sleep(2)

driver.close()
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'.

Comment: Martin creo que simplemente puedes leer el excel, puedes usar Pandas para ello, y luego con un `for` iteras visitando cada una de las direcciones. La url la puedes construir simplemente con algo como `"https://auto.io/en/users/inventory/{}/general".format(id)`, donde id es la variable del `for in` que itera sobre la columna/lista de ids.

Comment: Estuve tratando de armar el codigo pero no pude, en caso de tener una lista asi: `lista = ['f17510fb-4678-4230-82d3-3be50fbecb6b','6e296f1d-5edf-4d8e-b601-9feb4dc6e177''16d36513-c4ce-4128-bec4-2c8cf60129f9']` Como podria ser el for ir en el codigo? Desde ya agradezco mucho la ayuda @FJSevilla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La idea mas simple es cargar tu columna de ids con Pandas o cualquier otra biblioteca especializada desde tu Excel. Una ves que puedas iterar sobre las `ids` usas un `for in` y construyes cada url usando `str.format`:

```
lista = ['f17510fb-4678-4230-82d3-3be50fbecb6b',
         '6e296f1d-5edf-4d8e-‌​b601-9feb4dc6e177',
         '1‌​6d36513-c4ce-4128-be‌​c4-2c8cf60129f9']

for id in lista:
    url = "https://auto.io/en/users/inventory/{}/general".format(id.strip())
```

En tu código quedaría integrado así en un principio:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Martin/Desktop/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://auto.io/en/login/")
user= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form_username"]')
user.send_keys("email")
passwd = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="form_password"]')
passwd.send_keys("pass")
l_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login_submit"]')
l_button.click()
time.sleep(1)

lista = ['f17510fb-4678-4230-82d3-3be50fbecb6b',
         '6e296f1d-5edf-4d8e-‌​b601-9feb4dc6e177',
         '1‌​6d36513-c4ce-4128-be‌​c4-2c8cf60129f9']

for id in lista:
    url = "https://auto.io/en/users/inventory/{}/general".format(id.strip())
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(1)
    l_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="inventory_general"]/fieldset/div[1]/div[2]/span/span[2]/span')
    l_button.click()
```

Si tienes problemas con la carga de los elementos mírate los [Waits Explícitos.](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

---

**Edición:**

Cuando haces `my_list = list(reader)` lo que obtienes es una lista de listas donde cada lista interna es una fila:

```
[['301d5e7b-a75f-4962-f38f-1e6e5db90dcc'], ['f5b2b6ba-a4ce-4e17-b8f8-b8d912e4d6ec'], ...]
```

Dado que tu csv solo tiene una columna, si siempre va a ser así, no necesitas nada especial para leerlo, itera sobre las filas directamente:

```
with open("Ids para Pausar.csv", 'r') as my_file:
    for id in my_file:
        url = "https://platform.io/en/users/inventory/{}/general".format(id.strip())

        # Resto del codigo
```

Si tuviera más columnas puedes obtener la primera columna con algo como:

```
import csv
with open("Ids para Pausar.csv", 'r') as my_file:
    reader = csv.reader(my_file, delimiter=',')
    my_list = (row[0] for row in reader) # 0 es el indice de la primera columna
    for id in my_list:
        url = "https://platform.io/en/users/inventory/{}/general".format(id.strip())
```

Comment: Increible, me solucionaste la vida por segunda vez!!!! Abrazo

Comment: cuando leo my archivo de CSV me da este error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'. Tenes idea como solucionarlo??

Comment: ya la edite, yo descargo los ID y los tengo en un CSV. Pero cuando quiero correrlos en la cadena de la URL no puedo porque me dice que no es un strip

Comment: te comparto el enlace del archivo que lo cargue en el drive para que lo veas. [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0L1ZT-zXzKlQl9VczdfY1JKSkk/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: Necesitaria que el csv quede de la misma forma ya que lo descargo asi desde la pagina y puedo automatizarlo sin tener que modificarlo!

Comment: Esta terminado mi programa ahora! Jaja muchisimas gracias por la ayuda! Abrazo

Comment: Tenes idea de porque selenium una vez que hice los cambios en mis URL's no me guarda dichos cambios? una vez terminado cerre el driver y abri en mi browser y todo seguia iguail, no se hicieron los cambios por mas que puse save a cada cambio que realice!